# Data science: How to perform classification with yes / maybe labels?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science-model

I am working on a big data problem. I have millions of data points each with over a thousand categorical and numerical fields. A small number of them have labels and the idea is to build a model to predict the labels.

The problem is that my labels are unreliable. They are yes / maybe labels. I know with a high degree of certainty that the yes labels are correct. The issue is that for everything not labeled yes they could be either yes or no. There is no way for me to correct this problem either. I can't go looking for more data to fill in the gaps or hunt down the true label. I just have to work with what I've got.

I'm trying to come up with approaches for this problem but I am pretty stuck. The only idea I currently have is to segment the data and then look at the ratio in each segment. So for segment A I could say they are 2.5 times as likely to be a yes than the average.

I am hoping other people can help me come up with some approaches. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. [Semi-supervised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning) methods might be interesting in this case.

Comment: A form of semi-supervised learning called PU (positive and unlabelled) learning [(see Semi-Supervised Classification of Unlabeled Data (PU Learning) by Alon Agmon)](https://towardsdatascience.com/semi-supervised-classification-of-unlabeled-data-pu-learning-81f96e96f7cb) might be useful. This can be used when you only have labels for one class, so you could use this technique by treating your data labelled "maybe" as unlabelled data.